# element.tagname doesn't return <a> on links

Tags: javascript, iphone, tagname

I'm programming an iPhone app that uses a little bit of javascript code for get the element for a point on UIWebView.

I have a bit of experience on iPhone, but no experience on javascript, I found that code on a tutorial ([here](http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/07/11/customize-the-contextual-menu-of-uiwebview/))

```
// Javascript code
function MyAppGetHTMLElementsAtPoint(x,y) {
    var tags = ",";
    var e = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
    while (e) {
        if (e.tagName) {
            tags += e.tagName + ',';
        }
        e = e.parentNode;
    }
    return tags;
}

// iPhone code
    NSString *tags = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyAppGetHTMLElementsAtPoint(x,y);"]]
    if ([tags rangeOfString:@",A,"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"Link found");
        ....
    }
```

The problem is that I have tested this code with, for example, a google search webpage, and I don't get the "Link found" log.

I think that it may be because a page is not whole HTML, but I cannot do anything more.

Thanks!!

PD: I have the same problem, but not on all the pages, with the IMG tag (maybe it's because of CSS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @JuanMendes, the problem was on the coordinates that the iPhone passes to the javascript function.

```
// Not working code
// Searches the location on the main view, that is the full screen
CGPoint pt = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

// Working code
// Searches the location only on the webView
CGPoint pt = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.webView];
```

Thanks for the people that have help me with this, and especially for @JuanMendes

Comment: I have created a new answer because you only have suggested that it can be the problem, but I want to leave the correct code for anyone that runs into the same problem.

Comment: But, if you want, you can copy my iPhone code in your answer, and I would delete my answer and accept yours.

Answer (score 2):

Some modes of XHTML return `tagName` as you put it in the source, so it could be lower cased. Try calling

```
tags += e.tagName.toUpperCase() + ',';
```

If that's not the problem, what does the  `tags` string contain?

**Completely unrelated suggestion**

Arrays are the best way to create comma separated lists

```
function MyAppGetHTMLElementsAtPoint(x,y) {
    var tags = [];
    var e = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
    while (e) {
        if (e.tagName) {
            tags.push(e.tagName);
        }
        e = e.parentNode;
    }
    return tags.join(',');
}
```

I provided a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cgpVk/1/ that proves the function is working fine. You're probably not passing it the right coordinates

Comment: It contains this: this: ,DIV,DIV,LI,OL,DIV,DIV,DIV,DIV,DIV,DIV,DIV,DIV,DIV,BODY,HTML,

Comment: Are you sure you're clicking on a link?

Comment: And thanks for your "completely unrelated suggestion", it will help

Comment: @Asterix22 How can you be sure that you're passing it the right coordinates? Are there many links on the page? The following JSFiddle proves that your function works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/cgpVk/1/  It's probably something about the iphone implementation of webkit or that you're passing it the right coordinates.

Comment: Yes, I have been thinking on it and maybe I'm getting the coordinates on the whole screen and not only on the web page, I'll check it. Thanks! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging `e.tagName` each time? Then you can see what you're getting for the links.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting this: ,DIV,DIV,LI,OL,DIV,DIV,DIV,DIV,DIV,DIV,DIV,DIV,DIV,BODY,HTML,